# docker-compose + how to set ramdisk insted of volumes

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, ram

In docker-compose we set the following volumes:

```
volumes:
  - /var/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

So `/var/kafka-data` will mounted from `/var/lib/kafka/data`

Now we want to use `ramdisk` instead of mount between `/var/lib/kafka/data to /var/kafka-data`

The ramdisk command is like this

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=100G ramdisk1 /var/kafka
```

the question is how to set the `ramdisk` cli in the `docker-compose.yml` instead of `/var/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data`

Comment: Why would you do this? You're removing one of the code features of Kafka - durability

Comment: @cricket_007 . the point is , we want to use only the RAM memory and not the disk , as you know disk is much more slow then the RAM memory

Comment: You shouldn't store kafka data in RAM anyway, spinning disks are preferred. . The documentation even says so.

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you , I will choose the tmpfs as you said ,, ( do you preferred the tmpfs? )

Comment: Kafka data should always be available across reboots. I don't understand your use case here

Comment: A use case could be to run tests on a developer machine. Another could be to use NVRAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ramdisk command needs to be executed on the host and not in the docker container. Therefore, I would say add the `tmpfs` mount to the host `/etc/fstab`. same as shown below (example with tmpfs and ramdisk1)

```
tmpfs /var/kafka tmpfs uid=1001,gid=1001,size=10240m 0 0
ramdisk1  /data tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=100G  0  0
```

execute `mount -a` or restart the node to mount the folder.

Update your docker-compose

```
volumes:
  - /var/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Comment: I think in fstab should be    -->   ramdisk1 /var/kafka tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=100G  0  0

Comment: can you please correct he line that should be in fstab ?

Comment: please see that - https://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk , what I am asking is ramdisk not tmpfs as you wrote in your quastion , second your syntax isnt right see what I wrote -  ramdisk1 /var/kafka tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=100G 0 0

Comment: @jess tmpfs can be stored in RAM and optionally spill to disk

Comment: @cricket_007 this is the point we not want to split it to disk , so the syntax as I wrote is the right syntax - ramdisk1 /var/kafka tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=100G 0 0   ( we want to use only the RAM memory )

Comment: any way , if some one want to use tmpfs , then more right syntax is - tmpfs /var/kafka tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=10240M 0 0 ( because setings uid with statis value as 1001 , can make conflicts if its already used ) , ( or other example as - tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,noatime,nodev,size=10240G,mode=1777 0 0 )

Comment: The main idea is to mount this on the host and keep using the file volume on the docker-compose. You can have any command that suits you in the `/etc/fstab`

Comment: https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux @jess